# Flutter macOS build fails in Xcode Cloud with mismatching team certificate

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos

I started a fresh Flutter project for macOS and I have Xcode cloud setup to pull the project from Github. I also setup a [post clone CI script](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/cd#xcode-cloud) to install the Flutter env. I'm getting this error when the script runs `flutter build macos`:

```
macos/Runner.xcodeproj: error: No signing certificate "Mac Development" found: No "Mac Development" signing certificate matching team ID "*" with a private key was found. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

I have the project automatically signed with my Apple Development cert. Any clue what I'm missing here?

I noticed when I change the signing to manual in Xcode and I try to pull to the provisioning profiles it fails with this error:

```
no eligible profiles found for Runner matching the macOS platform with bundle identifier xxxxxx.
```

I have couple of profiles created for macOS in my account and they are associated with the Mac Development cert in my account as well. Does the Xcode project has some mismatching configs?

Worth noting that the iOS project is working fine and building successfully. It can pull the associated profiles with no issues.